# When the standardizing function doesn't return a standard deviation of 1

Tags: r

Given:

```
stdized = function(x)
{
    return (x-mean(x)/sd(x))
}
```

According to the [wiki page describing feature standardisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Standardization), the stdev of the output of this function should be 1. Yet:

```
> sd(stdized(c(1,2,3,4,5)))
[1] 1.581139
```

Why so?

Comment: You're missing parentheses. You want `return((x - mean(x)) / sd(x))`. Division takes precedence over subtraction.

Comment: That'll do it alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code as

```
    stdized = function(x)
    {
       return ((x-mean(x))/sd(x))
    }
```